# References for Forcing with Side Conditions

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

I'm looking for some good references about *Forcing with Side Conditions*, including expository papers that explain the main ideas with some details in order to give me a fairly clear insight of those set theoretic problems that are solvable using this approach. Any other reference is also welcome.

Comment: I believe the first reference is Stevo's paper *[A note on the proper forcing axiom](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~stevo/Todorcevic_Note_On_PFA.pdf)*. This was followed by Stevo's book **Partition problems in topology**.

Comment: An early expository presentation is Kozmider's paper *Models as side conditions* in **Set Theory: Techniques and Applications Curaçao 1995 and Barcelona 1996**, edited by Joan Bagaria, Carlos Di Prisco, Jean Larson, and A R D Mathias.

Comment: The paper "[Mitchell's Theorem Revisited](http://www.math.unt.edu/~jkrueger/paper27.pdf)" by Gilton-Krueger is also interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. S. Todorcevic, Notes on Forcing Axioms, Chapter 7.
2. Itay Neeman, Forcing with side conditions. Oberwolfach, 2011. http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/
3. B. Velickovic, G. Venturi, Proper forcing remastered.  http://www.math.cmu.edu/~eschimme/Appalachian/Pfr.pdf

Comment: Interesting references. Thank you very much.